# ...we are brought to this point

Tags: grammaticality, tenses

> I cannot say what role the *New York Times v. Sullivan* decision has
> played in bringing us to this point, if it has played any role at all,
> but I can say that it is a very big deal that we are brought to this
> point.

"are brought" What is this? Present preterit or something?

"have been brought" expresses what I need it to express, but, for some reason, "are brought" sounds closer to expressing what I mean--maybe because it's more active in the present moment? I don't know.

But is it even grammatically correct?

Comment: It's using _brought to this point_ as a predicate adjective. It's not a formal passive construction, because that would need the Perfect.

Comment: @JohnLawler OK, so it focuses attention on the "we" and not on the "bringing." That's why it sounds better to me in the context, because I want to call attention to our current dire situation and not so much the process of how we got here.

Comment: I couldn't say what it focuses attention on; that's an opinion and not syntactic.

Comment: I hope you'll do something about the repetition.